# Capital or small letters for geographic locations

Tags: ortografía, geografía

I'm a bit confused about when to use small or capital letters referring to locations (countries and cities).

Sentences like:

- Él es un estudiante en noruega y vive en Oslo
- Hoy viajo a Rio
- vamos a argetina
- Soy de brasil

So far I've looked at this [site](http://spanish.about.com/od/writtenspanish/a/capitalization.htm) without getting a general answer that applies to the examples above.

Comment: This link may help http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=may%25FAsculas&origen=RAE&lema=may%25FAsculas#47

Comment: There is already a discussion on this site http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/when-is-uppercase-used-in-english-but-lowercase-in-spanish which may help you too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: the names of countries and cities should be capitalized.

Also, the first letter of a sentence should be capitalized (like in "vamos" in your third sentence)

So, some of those examples are wrong. See the following corrections in bold

- El es un estudiante en **N**oruega y vive en Oslo
- Hoy viajo a **Río**  (í with accent)
- **V**amos a **A**rgentina
- Soy de **B**rasil

The following link (it is in Spanish) has all the rules for the use of capital letters and in the section 4.7 you can see that all geographical names should be capitalized.
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp

> 4.7. Los nombres propios geográficos (continentes, países, ciudades, comarcas, mares, ríos, etc.): América, África, Italia, Canadá, Toledo, Lima, las Alpujarras, la Rioja (comarca), la Mancha (comarca), el Adriático, el Mediterráneo, el Orinoco, el Ebro, los Andes, el Himalaya. Como se ve en los ejemplos, determinados nombres propios geográficos van necesariamente acompañados de artículo, como ocurre con las comarcas, los mares, los ríos y las montañas. En otros casos, como ocurre con determinados países, el uso del artículo es opcional: Perú o el Perú (→ el, 5). El artículo, en todos estos casos, debe escribirse con minúscula, porque no forma parte del nombre propio. Pero cuando el nombre oficial de un país, una comunidad autónoma, una provincia o una ciudad lleve incorporado el artículo, este debe escribirse con mayúscula: El Salvador, La Rioja (comunidad autónoma), Castilla-La Mancha (comunidad autónoma), La Pampa, La Habana, Las Palmas. Cuando el artículo forma parte del nombre propio no se realiza en la escritura la amalgama con las preposiciones de o a: Mi padre acaba de regresar de El Cairo (no del Cairo); Este verano iremos a El Salvador (no al Salvador).

Comment: But bear in mind that sometimes the adjective referring to the origin sounds exactly like the country, and must not be capitalized, like in _soy noruega_ (I'm Norwegian) or in _ella es argentina_ (she's Argentinian).

Comment: Good point @MikMik but the rule still holds. The name of the country is capitalized, the _nationality_ (gentilicio) is not.

Comment: Of course. But I was thinking that for learners the fact that some nationalities sound like the name of the country might be confusing, and they could have a hard time understanding why "soy argentina" is not capitalized and "soy de Argentina" is.

Comment: Of course @MikMik, that's why I said **"Good point"**